# Icons rendering is very slow in Edge browser

Tags: css, svg, microsoft-edge

In our website, we are showing icons for stylized check boxes. The icons are rendered from SVG file. These icons are loaded very slowly in Edge browser (almost 10 seconds). It works fine in IE and Chrome. Please suggest some options to improve the image loading time for Edge. PFB the screenshot with check boxes.

[image]

**Implementation details**

The HTML elements corresponding to the checkbox are added dynamically while getting response from web service. Logic is implemented in pure JS and styles are done using SASS.

Comment: Try to clear Edge browser cache and cookie, and check whether it will decrease the loading time? Besides, can you post enough code to reproduce the problem, it might be easier to narrow down the problem?

Comment: It is like Docker on Windows. Don't use it.

Comment: We are not using Docker. Its custom code that we developed only :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a web service to populate the checkbox, at first we need to improve the performance, you could try to use F12 developer tool or set timer to check it. Besides, you could also optimize Image Usage, and try to use asynchronous methods to call the web service.

Besides, in my opinion(since you didn't post the related code), I suggest you could try to use CSS or Javascript to create the custom checkbox with check mark, instead of using SVG, because, by using the CSS style, when add the new checkbox, we could just add the related CSS style for it.

You could refer to the following code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {

            //call the web service to get the checkbox items.

            //add new checkbox items with CSS style. 
            $("#dynamiccontent").append("<label class='container'>TwoTwo<input type = 'checkbox' > <span class='checkmark'></span> </label >");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html code:

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdd"  value="Add"/>
<div id="dynamiccontent">
    <label class="container">
        One
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>

    <label class="container">
        Two
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* Customize the label (the container) */
    .container {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 22px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }

        /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
        .container input {
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
        }

    /* Create a custom checkbox */
    .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: #eee;
    }

    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #2196F3;
    }

    /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
    .checkmark:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }

    /* Show the checkmark when checked */
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
    .container .checkmark:after {
        left: 9px;
        top: 5px;
        width: 5px;
        height: 10px;
        border: solid white;
        border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
</style>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Reference: [How TO - Custom Checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)